# piping find into grep

Tags: bash, grep, find, pipe

I am trying to pipe find into grep with the negative match option but I don't get the desired results. I am using the Ubuntu subshell for Windows and running the command:

```
find / -name CCP.cf | grep -v '*denied'
```

This produces the output (a lot omitted for brevity):

```
find: ‘/mnt/c/Config.Msi’: Permission denied
find: ‘/mnt/c/Intel/IntelOptaneData’: Permission denied
find: ‘/mnt/c/Program Files/WindowsApps’: Permission denied
```

Is this printout from the find and can it not be directed to grep?
Essentially I want to be able to use find and it return the directory of the file to me (I'm going to wrap it into a function later).

Comment: You're grepping the filenames, not the contents of the files. Is that what you want?

Comment: `*denied` is not a valid regular expression. `*` needs a pattern before it.

Comment: That output is from `find`, it's just telling you that there are some directories that it can't search because you don't have permission to read those directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error messages go to standard error, but you're only piping standard output to `grep`. To redirect stderr as well, use `2>&1`, this redirects `stderr` (FD 1) to `stdout` (FD 1), which has already been redirected to the pipe.

```
find / -name CCP.cf 2>&1 | grep -v 'Permission denied'
```

You could also just filter out all error messages:

```
find / -name CCP.cf 2>/dev/null
```